# The possibility of using perfect tenses in complex sentenses referring to the sphere of the past that play themselves the role of the direct object

Tags: tense

The usage of the present perfect tenses with the markers of past time has been noticed in as much as 20% of BE colloquial speech. But it is still difficult for the non-native speakers to discern correctly in what cases it can be relevant because this usage doesn't fall under conventional rules (i.e. Past Indefinite or Past Continuous with clauses or adverbials of past time).

The above said, could it be possible for the perfect tenses to be put on in the following patterns:

1. I just want to know how you have spent your parents' money when you studied at the university.
2. I just want to know how you have been spending your parents' money when you studied at the university.
3. Some time ago I wanted to know how he had spent his parents' money when he studied at the university.
4. Some time ago I wanted to know how he had been spending his parents' money when he studied at the university.
5. They asked me about something I have said years ago.
6. They asked me about something I have been saying years ago.
7. They asked me about something I had said years ago.
8. They asked me about something I had been saying years ago.

Comment: Sentences 2, 5 and 6 (looking quickly) are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

When the time-phrase consigns the action to the past, *thereby excluding the present*, the present-perfect is not viable. I've put the time phrase in brackets and the proper tense in superscript below.

I won't address the past perfect forms in this answer. Could you  ask about that in a separate question?

NOT VIABLE:

I just want to know how you **have spent** <sup>spent</sup> your parents' money [when you studied at the university.]

I just want to know how you **have been spending** <sup>were spending</sup> your parents' money [when you studied at the university.]

They asked me about something I **have said** <sup>said</sup> [years ago].

They asked me about something I **have been saying** <sup>was saying</sup> [years ago].

And to address a comment in which the commenter has misunderstood what I mean by "excluding the present", this sentence is viable:

> They asked me about something I *have been saying* [since I graduated from school long ago.]

Even though there is a reference to the distant past in "long ago", the relevant word from the time phrase is **since**, which means "from then until *now*".  The time phrase does not exclude the present but implicitly includes it.

Comment: Thank you! If I haven't misunderstood you, when we scratch out the phrases in brackets then perfect tenses will become possible? I.e. "They asked me about something I have said" can be viable?

Comment: @Eugene:  Correct.The present perfect is grammatical if "years ago" is removed from that sentence.  The simple past is also grammatical there.

Comment: Couldn't you, please, elucidate the difference in perception to me between "They asked me about something I have said" and "They asked me about something I said"? I.e. in what time lapse does "I have said" lies?

Comment: "When the time-phrase consigns the action to the past, thereby excluding the present, the present-perfect is not viable." That is inaccurate: What have you done since you finished school five years ago?

Comment: There's more to the present perfect than time.  "They asked me about something *I've said*"  could fit a number of contexts; for example: I said it recently;  I have said it on more than one occasion; what I said has some bearing upon or relevance to the present.

Comment: @Lambie: the time phrase is "*since* you finished school" and thus it connects to the present, rather than excludes the present. "Since" means "from then up to *now*"

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice You comments since the outset here have not been helpful. You started by saying that "they asked me" is not relevant in terms of choice of tense. I used the OP's sentences and corrected them; specifically with regard to his/her existing sentences.

Comment: "They asked me about something I have said"=No. Not viable.  "They asked me about something I said". Yes.

Answer (score -1):

Look what you say about BrE is false. This is the "rule": the past perfect is used to point to something that **precedes** another action in the past. That preceding action can be stated in black and white or be implied. That said, there are other issues with the sentences.

1. I just want to know how you have spent your parents' money when you studied at the university. [BUZZER]

- how you **spent** your parents' money when you **studied** [no buzzer]

The spending and studying is finished, over.

2. I just want to know how you **have been spending** your parents' money when you **studied** at the university. [BUZZER]

**No, not if you keep **when you studied.****

Yes, if you change it, like this:
I just want to know how you **have been spending** your parents' money while **you are studying, or have been studying at university**.

3. and 4) are fine.
4. They asked me about something I have said years ago. [BUZZER]

**No, why**? Because **asked me is specific and finished**, so:

They **asked me** about something I **said years ago**. [no buzzer: ago takes the simple past]

Also, ago always goes with simple past or a completed (continuous) past.

6. They **asked me** about something I **have been saying** years ago.

**No**, because they asked me is finished, so you cannot have been saying it years ago.

- They **asked me** about something I **was saying** years ago.
  OR
- They asked me about something I had said OR had been saying years before.

7. and 8) are correct because asked me is "preceded by" an action in the past perfect.

Basic rule: The present perfect and present prefect continuous are used in relation to the present time of speaking and are preceded by another action in the simple past.

Basic rule: The past perfect and past perfect continuous are used in relation to the simple past tense or imperfect past tense.

Comment: "They asked me" is not relevant to the choice of tense.  It could be "they will ask me" or "they are asking me" or "they had asked me" or "they have asked me". What governs the choice of tense is the time-phrase, "years ago" and "when ... studied".

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Basic rule 1 (see my answer): I've been teaching English or have taught English [for] a long time. [said now, in the present] *versus* Basic rule 2 (see my answer) They asked me  or were asking me if I **had taught** or **had been teaching**  for a long time. Obviously, I cannot give every possible combination of tenses. I have given the ones relevant to the question. simple past=goes with ago. I left five minutes ago.

Comment: "They asked me" etc.  is relevant to the question: 
They asked me about something I have said years ago. They asked me about something I have been saying years ago. [buzzer on those two]
They **asked me** about something I **had said** years ago. [before]
They **asked me** about something I **had been saying years ago**. Those two are fine. *They will ask me* is **not part of the question**.

Comment: The tense of the main clause ("they asked me", "they will ask me", "they had asked me", "they have asked me") has no bearing upon the choice of tense  in the clause headed by "what".  That choice in the examples sentence is driven by the time-phrase ("when you studied" and "years ago").

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Again, the OP did not ask about: they will ask me or they had asked me. The **OP asked about "They asked me" at the beginning of a sentence!** And I have corrected his sentences.